# Declarative External Service Suddenly Getting Media Type Response Error

Tags: json, external-services

Open API 2.0 schema used as Invocable Apex with Flow that has been working for six months. Two days ago we started getting an error on the 200 response.

```
Expected declared response media type application/json, but got text/plain; charset=UTF-8 for operation get
```

We have a Case opened since we didn't touch the schema and barring a change by the other party (Federal Govt), then must've been a change at Salesforce but I'm hoping someone has a suggestion for how we might edit our schema now to overcome this error.

The responses which look like this in Postman used to be recognized as JSON. This is valid JSON and will format correctly if I put into an editor. (The below is public info)

```
{"resultCount":1,"results":[{"created_epoch":"1135112244000","enumeration_type":"NPI-2","last_updated_epoch":"1223408717000","number":"1588640692","addresses":[{"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","address_purpose":"MAILING","address_type":"DOM","address_1":"1364 CLIFTON RD NE","address_2":"ROOM HB48","city":"ATLANTA","state":"GA","postal_code":"303221064","telephone_number":"404-686-7041","fax_number":"404-712-5731"},{"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","address_purpose":"LOCATION","address_type":"DOM","address_1":"1364 CLIFTON RD NE","city":"ATLANTA","state":"GA","postal_code":"303221064","telephone_number":"404-686-7041","fax_number":"404-712-5731"}],"practiceLocations":[],"basic":{"organization_name":"EMORY UNIVERSITY","organizational_subpart":"NO","enumeration_date":"2005-12-20","last_updated":"2008-10-07","status":"A","authorized_official_first_name":"Jimmy","authorized_official_last_name":"Hatcher","authorized_official_middle_name":"T","authorized_official_telephone_number":"4046862983","authorized_official_title_or_position":"CFO Emory Healthcare","authorized_official_name_prefix":"Mr."},"taxonomies":[{"code":"282N00000X","desc":"General Acute Care Hospital","state":"GA","license":"044-049","primary":true}],"identifiers":[{"code":"05","desc":"MEDICAID","issuer":null,"identifier":"00000712A","state":"GA"},{"code":"06","desc":"MEDICARE OSCAR/Certification","issuer":null,"identifier":"110010","state":"GA"}],"endpoints":[],"other_names":[]}]}
```

The relevant path statement is:

```
"paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Get NPPES NPI data",
        "consumes": ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
        "produces": ["application/json"],
```

Comment: Salesforce hasn't had a release recently, so it's *probable* that the API got broken on the far end somehow. If it's not too difficult, I suggest reviewing a response from the API manually in Postman or some other tool. Short of that, you'd have to change the `produces` line to `text/plain`, assign it to an in/out flow variable, then pass it to Apex for deserialization.

Comment: I was curious if maybe Salesforce did a bug fix over the weekend in this area. The response I posted above is from Postman. Salesforce is reading that as text/plain but that is a complete JSON response above. Postman sees it as such. Changing to text/plain is kind of a non-starter as this is in our managed package and been fine for 6 months. Also already integrated with many flows.

Comment: Did you check the response *headers*, though?

Comment: ...this is why the best practice is to continuously monitor all interfaces. Google "synthetic monitoring".

Comment: The response headers does look like the issue. So I'm assuming this means that inadvertenly I think, this was changed by the other provider? It's `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Will look into how synthetic monitoring may have helped here thx, though we weren't developing anything but guess would have gotten to bottom of issue faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear the issue was the response header was changed by the 3rd party from `application/json` to `text/plain` based on the Postman information.